# `content-security-policy: default-src https:;` blocks resource loading at inline 1:1

Tags: http-headers, content-security-policy

I have set `Content-Security-Policy: default-src https:; report-uri https://rootkea.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/enforce` on https://csp.rootkea.me/

Whenever I visit the website, the console says:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at inline (“default-src”). rootkea.me:1:1

At 1:1 I have `<!DOCTYPE html>` as can be seen from the source:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="GitLab Pages">
    <title>Plain HTML site using GitLab Pages</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/css/ec5b55aee5efed4317d1380a75fc4c3df003f096/style.css'/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="https://rootkea.me/">Home</a>
      <a href="https://blog.rootkea.me/" target="_blank">Blog</a>
    </div>

    <h1>Hello World!</h1>

  </body>
</html>
```

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poor debugging on my part. I should've debugged in fresh Firefox profile first.

Anyways, the culprit was the [Google Analytics Opt-out Add-on (by Google)](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout) addon. I disabled it and no more CSP error in console.